# Show legend.text as integer instead of decimal numbers in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataframe `dd` as follows:

```
dd <- structure(list(city = c("bj", "cd", "cq", "dg", 
"fs", "gz", "hz", "hz", "jh", "ks", "xm", 
"sh", "tj", "wz", "wx", "xy", "yw"), 
    nums = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1), longitude = c(116.413383697123, 104.081533510425, 106.558434155377, 
    113.758420457876, 113.128512195497, 113.27143134446, 120.215511803722, 
    114.423558016582, 119.653436190529, 120.98745249795, 118.096435499767, 
    121.480538860177, 117.209523214671, 120.706476890356, 120.318583288106, 
    108.715422451433, 120.081580993059), latitude = c(39.9109245472996, 
    30.6558218784164, 29.5689962453389, 23.0273084116434, 23.0277587507889, 
    23.135336306695, 30.2530829816935, 23.1163588547256, 29.0846393855137, 
    31.3908634250819, 24.4854066051763, 31.235929042252, 39.093667843404, 
    28.0010854044722, 31.4988097326857, 34.3354762933686, 29.3111498754101
    )), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have plotted the map with the code below:

```
library(mapdata)
china <- map("china", plot = F)
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = china, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = 'grey80', show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data = dd, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = nums), alpha = 0.8, color = '#FD9FA4') +
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  theme_economist_white(gray_bg = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(data = dd, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, label = city), size = 5, family = "STKaiti") +
  theme_bw(base_family = "STKaiti") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "right",
          legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 18),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 25, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", margin = margin(0, 0, 10, 0)),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5, color="black", margin = margin(0, 0, 20, 0)),
          plot.caption = element_text(size = 20, color = "black")
        )
```

`legend.text` plot:

[image]

But as you may noticed, `legend.text` is not integer as the original data, how could convert the `legend.text` as `1, 2, 3` instead of `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3`?

I have tried with `dd$nums= as.numeric(as.character(dd$nums))`, but it doesn't work out.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you make nums an integer when creating the data frame?  Or wrap it in `as.integer()` in ggplot.  Also try to make a minimal example (get rid of all the code you don't need to illustrate what is happening).

Comment: Add `scale_size_continuous(breaks = 1:3)`

Comment: Thanks, @Phil, your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are plenty of ways to approach this, but this method is pretty minimal and just requires wrapping the `nums` argument in `factor`, ie:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = china, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = 'grey80', show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data = dd, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = factor(nums)), alpha = 0.8, color = '#FD9FA4') +
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "nums"))
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this gives `legend.title` as `factor(nums)`, how could I changed it to `nums`?

Comment: I've edited the answer above to add in how to change the legend title though the `guides(...)` function.